# Wordpress plugin for daily tips

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is there any plugin to create daily tips in the wordpress and then show them on the site

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found one, its simple but serve the purpose
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tips/

Answer (score 0):

Check more options
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/st-daily-tip/ 
*Simple plugin to display different daily tips from a list. Option to select specific date or day of week to display a tip.*

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tip-of-the-day/ 
*A simple tip random tips generator that were writting by you. It is used as a widget*